# I try to use this command: PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File install-sshd.ps1 but I keep getting error

Tags: powershell, pycharm, windows-10

I get this error: PowerShell : The argument 'install-sshd.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter.
At line:1 char:1

- PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File install-sshd.ps1
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The argument 'i...File parameter.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
  ```

In the powershell terminal and i need to do this so that i can access the terminal of pycharm i am kinda new and i have been trying the last hours to solve with any way possible but still no results if anyone can help i would appreciate!

I tried the command from title from what i found here i thought it would work but then another problem it keeps pissing me off and my patience is running down but still my confidence keeps me and i cant advance with my python project

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: The error message is telling you that a file named `install-sshd.ps1` doesn't exist in the _current directory_.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be in the directory where the script is located. Try navigating to wherever the script is

`ps> cd C:\scriptlocation`

then run your command.

`PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\install-sshd.ps1`

or reference the location in the -file parameter

`PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "c:\script_location\install-sshd.ps1"`